# How to work with user-agent to download a webpage using Wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to download this page using Wget. Here is the page link:

> http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=250972882769&si=a8iGAIchyvEbn7KveYFZ5QbEE7o%3D&print=all&category=31387

And here is my cmd:

> wget -O ebay.html --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" "http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=250972882769&si=a8iGAIchyvEbn7KveYFZ5QbEE7o%3D&print=all&category=31387"

When I use it to access the page using a browser it works fine. When I use Wget, it downloads another page, not the original one. I think the problem is for user-agent. What's the solution?

Comment: Try using Fiddler and see the structure of the http request when you open the URL in your browser. just mimic the structure into your wget command.

Comment: will you give a simple example ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem isn't user-agent, it's a missing cookie or cookies.  The solution is

1. Retrieve the normal product page with wget --save-cookies=ebay-cookies ,
2. Fish the "Print" link URL out of that HTML file.  (I did this by hand, you should obviously write a script to do it.)
3. Retrieve the "Print" URL with wget --load-cookies=ebay-cookies

I tried it with a random product page; it worked.

Comment: how did you find out that ebay-cookies is the word to enable in case I do it with some other site how to find out which cookies to enable

Comment: ebay-cookies is just the name of the file I chose to store the cookies in.  Use whatever name you like.  The important part is the use of --save-cookies to save the site cookies and --load-cookies to load and send them back to the website.